# Exponentiation using list comprehension

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to solve the following exercise (I'm learning Haskell):

> Define x^n using a list comprehension.

And I'm struggling to find a solution.

Using recursion or fold, the solution is not complicated (for instance, `foldr (*) 1 [x | c <- [1..n]]`). However, using only list comprehension it gets difficult (at least for me).

In order to solve the problem, I'm trying to create a list of x^n elements and then get the length. Generating a list of x*n elements is easy, but I fail to generate a list of x^n elements.

```
ppower x n = length [1 | p <- [1..x], c <- [1..n]]
```

returns a list of x*n elements giving a wrong result. Any ideas on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps try nesting two or more list comprehensions

Comment: Certanly, the question is how to go about it

Comment: Hmm it doesn't look like it is easily doable without recursion. Where did you find this exercise?

Comment: I found it in "Introduction to functional programming" (Bird/Wadlers), first edition, in the section related to list comprehensions.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this exercise with just the functions introduced up until that point in the book, unless you take `n` to be a known constant rather than a function parameter. I heard you can email Bird and ask for clarification.

Comment: I sent him an email, if I get feedback, I'll post it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @n.m. I asked Richard Bird and he kindly replied. I posted the answer. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @n.m suggested, I asked Richard Bird (author of the book "Introduction to functional programming", first edition, the book where I got the exercise) for an answer/guidance in solving this exercise. He kindly replied and here I post the answer he gave me:

> Since a list comprehension returns a list not a number, x^n cannot be
>   defined as an instance of a list comprehension. Your solution x^n =
>   product [x | c <- [1..n]] is the correct one.

So, I guess I'll stick to the solution I posted (and discarded for using recursion):

```
foldr (*) 1 [x | c <- [1..n]]
```

He didn't say anything about creating a list of x^n elements with lists comprehensions (no recursion) though as @David Fletcher and @n.m point out in their comments, it might be impossible.

Comment: Wow.. i can not believe that this can be an exercise in a book targeting to teach you something. This turns out to be my previous answer (check the edits) that i have shamefully deleted. `pow n x = product [y | y <- replicate n x]`. I did this and a few moments later i have thought, "why in the world one should use a list comprehension for this job..?" You can always do `product $ replicate n x`. No offence but i wouldn't bother reading that book further. Try Graham Hutton's Programming in Haskell instead.

Comment: The book is incredibly good: it teaches you functional programming (not bound to haskell) in a mathematical way. The exercises are tough and lead you to think out of the box and try new solutions or explore new ways in order to solve them (which is great!). As I pointed out in my question, my premises to solve this exercise included no recursion or pattern matching (these techniques are well known and make the solution to the exercise trivial). I only added this answer to help anyone who tries to solve this exercise (or similar) trying to use list comprehension as well

Answer (score 4):

A naturally-occurring exponential comes from `sequence`:

```
length (sequence [[1..x] | _ <- [1..n]])
```

If you haven't seen `sequence` yet, it's quite a general function but
when used with lists it works like:

```
sequence [xs1, ... , xsk] = [[x1, ... xk] | x1 <- xs1, ... , xk <- xsk]
```

But this is really cheating since `sequence` is defined recursively.

---

If you want to use nothing but length and list comprehensions I think
it might be impossible.  The rest of this answer will be sketchy and I half
expect someone to prove me wrong.  However:

We'll try to prove that such an expression can only compute values up
to some finite power of *x* or *n*, and therefore can't compute values
as big as *x^n* for arbitrary *x* and *n*.

Specifically we show by induction on the structure of expressions that
any expression *expr* has an upper bound *ub(expr, m) = m^k* where *m*
is the maximum of the free variables it uses, and *k* is a known finite
power which we could calculate from the structure of the expression *expr*.

(When we look at the whole expression, *m* will be *max x n*.)

Our upper bounds on list expressions will be bounds on both the length of the list and also bounds on any of
its elements (and lengths of its elements, etc.).

For example if we have `[x..y]` and we know that *x <= m* and *y <= m*, we
know that all the elements are *<= m* and the length is also *<= m*.
So we have *ub([x..y], m) = m^1*.

The tricky case is the list comprehension:

```
[eleft | x1 <- e1, ... , xk <- ek]
```

The result will have length equal to *length e1 * ... * length ek*, so
an upper bound for it would be the product of the upper bounds for
*e1* to *ek*, or if *m^i* is the maximum of these then an upper bound
would be *(m^i)^k = m^(i*k)*.

To get a bound on the elements, suppose expression *eleft* has *ub(eleft, m') = m'^j*.  It can use *x1
... xk*.  If *m^i* is an upper bound for these, as above, we need to
take *m' = m^i* and so *ub(eleft, m) = (m^i)^j = m^(i*j)*

As a conservative upper bound for the whole list comprehension *e* we
could take *ub(e, m) = m^(i*j*k)*.

I should really also work through cases for pattern matching
(shouldn't be a problem because the parts matched are smaller than
what we already had), `let` definitions and functions (but we banned
recursion, so we can just fully expand these before we start), and
list literals like `[x,37,x,x,n]` (we can throw their lengths
into *m* as initially-available values).

If infinite lists like `[x..]` or `[x,y..]` are allowed they would need some
thinking about.  We can construct `head` and `filter`, which means we can get
from an infinite list to its first element matching a predicate, and that looks suspiciously like a way to get recursive functions.  I don't
*think* it's a problem since 1. they are only arithmetic sequences and
2. we'll have to construct any numbers we want to use in the
predicate.  But I'm not certain here.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do as follows;

```
pow :: Int -> Int -> Int
pow 0 _ = 1
pow 1 x = x
pow n x = length [1 | y <- [1..x], z <- [1..pow (n-1) x]]
```

so `pow 3 2` would return 8

Comment: One of the premises of the problem is solving it without using recursion. Thanks for your answer anyway